# Android Abrir um aplicativo a partir de outro por link e com passagem de parâmetros

Tags: android, ios, url, autenticação, parâmetros

Estamos desenvolvendo um App que será uma Store e ficará responsável pelo login e autenticação do usuário (será gerado um token toda vez que a Store for aberta e as credenciais do usuário sejam colocadas).

A ideia é que, quando o usuário abra a Store, faça o login e o essa autenticação (token) seja salva localmente e ao chamar algum aplicativo, este seja passado como parâmetro pro próximo aplicativo.

Caso o usuário abra um aplicativo já instalado, este deve chamar a Store, fazer login e o aplicativo anterior seja chamado novamente só que desta vez com os parâmetros da autenticação.

Vimos que é possível fazer essa chamada de um app ao outro com passagem de parâmetros em uma URL custom no iOS. Porém não conseguimos verificar uma solução similar no Android. Existe alguma forma nativa de fazer isso no Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para passar parâmetros para a nova aplicação, você cria um novo Intent e passa o mapa dos parâmetros

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
appIntent.putExtra("nomePrimeiraChave","valorPrimeiraChave");
appIntent.putExtra("nomeSegundaChave","valorSegundaChave");
startActivity(appIntent);
```

Comment: Mas desse jeito você chama uma Intent, não um outro App com esses parâmetros, correto?

Comment: No Android você inicia uma nova APP via intent.

Comment: Queria uma solução de chamada via link como iOs, mas pelo visto terá que ser uma solução pra cada plataforma. A ideia era construir híbrido utilizando um mesmo padrão de chamada de outras apps de forma nativa.